# Linux sudo is working slow after changing the hostname

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have changed my hostname in linux mint and after that my sudo works slow I mean how to change the etc/sudoers back again to work properly or there is anything else that I have to change

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you probably need to edit `/etc/hosts` to reflect your new hostname

otherwise it tries to find info about it via DNS (and timeouts, most probably)

look for:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost  oldname
```

and change to:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost  newname
```

Of course change only the line corresponding to oldname. 
Above I gave an an example of a machine which isn't connected to the net...

Below I give an example of a machine which have an IP:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
a.b.c.d    oldname     <-- just edit that line
```

Comment: @saurabh: did it help? (you should also look into /etc/resolv.conf to find out if you are using the host files or another mechanism...) (and I could also be wrong on the reason of the slowness after a changed hostname, but it seems you are in this case)

Comment: Can you explain why did it happen I mean why do the sudo cmd got slow

Comment: it made probably more than sudo slow: any time a command was looking for your hostname, it tried first /etc/hosts, and then asked the DNS...

Answer (score 5):

**Problem solved**. I describe to help others.

I've had the same problem. All configurations were correct, but login via ssh and sudo were extremely slow.

**cat /etc/hostname** was correct, but something did not work.

I solved by changing the hostname NOT from the file but by the command

**hostname name-of-the-host**

In this way the problem has disappeared. Probably using the hostname command are done other operations and the modification is more complete than just modifying the **/etc/hostname** file manually.

Answer (score 1):

Slowliness can be caused by not being able to resolve hostnames. This might be because of wrong entries in **/etc/hosts** or because of wrong settings in **/etc/resolv.conf**

Verify both so they be correctly configured. After that continue to the **sudoers** file.

Have you used the old hostname in the sudoers file, then update the sudoers content to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 1):

find out what your current hostname is:

```
hostname -f
```

Edit the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

change

```
127.0.0.1 oldhostname
```

to

```
127.0.0.1 current_hostname
```